# Perform element-wise operation on numpy string array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

say I have a numpy array like this `io = np.asarray(['hello world','hello Graz', 'hello all'])`. Now its shape is `io.shape (3,)`. I would like to perform a split per each element. I know this works `splituf = lambda i: np.asarray([item.split(" ",1) for item in i])`. Because the real life application will be on much larger array I'd like to avoid the for loop and use vectorized operation.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can used pandas library. It is built uses numpy, providing rich documentation and wonderful operations like pivot, graphs, element-wise operations,... lots of them

**Note**: pandas is not a replacement for numpy.

[Pandas element wise operation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#applying-elementwise-python-functions)

Here is one special case of element wise operation

```
>>> sam = np.arange(15)
>>> print sam
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]

>>> print pd.rolling_apply(sam, 2, lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
[ nan   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a collection nu py functions that applies the Python `str` operations to elemets of an array

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html

This includes a `np.char.split`.

In my limited experience these aren't significantly faster than a list comprehension because they still call Python functions, not fast compiled `numpy`c`code.
 If the split occurs at the same point in each string , eg`a[:5],a[5:]`, we might be able to do some dtype conversion.

The result will be 2d, right?

Comment: Thanks,
Unfortunately the split is not at the same paint, it will be at the first whitespace. Hence, yes, the result will be 2D: the first column with the first word for each line and the second column with the remaining words for each line. I have timed my lambda function vs np.char.split and the second one is faster. It's not indeed a numpy C code, but indeed remove the for loop in my lambda. However, I still think there must be a numpy way.

Comment: The array data buffer consists of bytes, grouped by the dtype string size.  But the split point will be different in each string.  Which means the number of bytes in each segment will differ.  So fast numpy operations like reshape or changing strides won't work.  You could write your won cython code to iterate through the buffer.  But it's not a common numpy operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join and re.split

```
import numpy as np
import re

io = np.asarray(['hello world','hello Graz', 'hello all'])
print(re.split('[ -]', '-'.join(io)))
```